# Jquery store form inputs in variable on rewrite to doc they have their original values

Tags: jquery, forms, input, replacewith

I am working with jQuery building a Template form for a print shop. Users can fill out the form and click a "Preview" button. At this point, I store the form in a variable and rewrite the text inputs using replaceWith() to swap the input out of the table cell and replace it with its' value.
At this point I show an "Edit More" button in case they want to reconsider their input.
So,... I then write the html in the stored variable back into the form, but surprise, the text input values are the original defaults from before user entry.
This is a pretty complex project. I hate to post code because I feel it will just complicate the discussion. I hope someone has already had this experience so knows just what is up! :-)
Thanks all.

Comment: do you mean the history values on the text boxes???

Comment: how are you storing the "form in a variable"?

Comment: @gov I am interested in your comment about history. I thought history only had variables and methods that applied to browser navigation. Can yo explain a little please?

Comment: @Emmet: I simply stored the html() of the containing div. I was a little surprised that there needed to be some real time initiation for this to not reflect the inputs with their entered values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I would rewrite some of your code using jQuery's [**`.detach()`**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method. It lets you store the elements you would normally be removing into a variable so they can then be reinserted back into the DOM at a later point in time.

You will still be able to interact with the detached elements as regular jQuery objects, but you won't see them on the page.

Here's an example:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    var detachedInput = '';
    var detachedBtn = '';

    $('#preview').click(function(){
        // store elements for later use
        detachedInput = $('#input').detach();
        detachedBtn = $(this).detach();

        // whatever you're trying to do with the output
        //...this is just an example, and not a very good one at that
        $('body').html($(detachedInput).val());
        $('<button>Edit</button>').appendTo('body')
            .click(function(){
                $('body').empty()
                    .append(detachedInput)
                    .append(detachedBtn);
            });
    });

});
</script>

<input id='input' />
<button id='preview'>Preview</button>
```

As a side note, posting some code usually does help as it gives everyone a better idea of what you're trying to do.